# Arduino Nano 33 IoT StandardFirmataPlus

Tags: arduino-nano, firmata, johnny-five

newbie here. So I've been trying to upload StandardFirmataPlus into my Arduino Nano 33 IoT so that I can program in Johnny-Five. However I have this issue.

[image]

I've checked that my port is connected and that the libraries are up to date. The [docs](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/examples/StandardFirmataPlus/StandardFirmataPlus.ino) say that if my board does not enough flash or RAM then the code wouldn't work. The code seems to work fine on other boards which have the same memory such as the Arduino UNO. My board is not a clone. And I've also checked that my Board Manager is set to "SAMD". If anyone has faced this issue and resolved, do share how you did it. Thanks in advance. If I've mentioned anything wrong do correct me =).

EDIT 1: I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.5. Arduino version 1.8.13. All I did was to try compiling the code. This is the Arduino IDE.

EDIT 2: Error Messages:

In file included from /Users/thebird/Desktop/Code/Arduino1/libraries/Firmata/Firmata.h:17:0,
from /Users/thebird/Desktop/Code/Arduino1/libraries/Firmata/examples/StandardFirmataPlus/StandardFirmataPlus.ino:49:
/Users/thebird/Desktop/Code/Arduino1/libraries/Firmata/Boards.h:824:2: error: #error "Please edit Boards.h with a hardware abstraction for this board"
#error "Please edit Boards.h with a hardware abstraction for this board"
^~~~~
Multiple libraries were found for "Firmata.h"
Used: /Users/thebird/Desktop/Code/Arduino1/libraries/Firmata
Not used: /private/var/folders/kx/l1lw7kfn0t387jt7bd3ccg3h0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/D1572E71-F02B-4F61-BAF9-E73A3ABEB39A/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/Firmata
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino NANO 33 IoT.

[image]

Comment: what is the issue?  ... you did not include the error message printout

Comment: Hello, sorry about that, I thought it was only 2 lines, I've added the error screenshot to my question.

Comment: why are you bothering with screenshots? ... it is much easier and much more useful to add the actual text ... screenshot of text cannot be used for doing web searches so most people won't even bother to look at your post

Comment: Hello, sorry this is my first time asking a question here. Yeah I've learnt my mistake, thank you =). I've also added the text for the errors.